# MUI Backdrop goes behind MUI Dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a loading overlay that uses the MUI Backdrop component. This works perfectly fine until I have a MUI Dialog open or a MUI Drawer open. In these scenarios, the Backdrop component renders behind the Dialog or Drawer. I have tried even throwing an `!important` on the zIndex of the Backdrop and setting it to 10000 and it will still render behind the Dialog or Drawer every time.

Has anyone else ever had this issue and been able to figure out how to get the Backdrop to always show up on top of any element on the page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
<Backdrop
  sx={{
    color: "#fff",
    zIndex: (theme) =>
      Math.max.apply(Math, Object.values(theme.zIndex)) + 1,
  }}
>
  <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
</Backdrop>
```

Loading overlay's `zIndex` is set to a value larger than all values inside [`theme.zIndex`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Here in theme.zIndex.drawer will return the zIndex of drawer and by adding 1 it will get the maximum zIndex. I've used this on my project and it worked.

```
<Backdrop
  sx={{
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
    zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  }}
  open={loading}
>
  {/* Your design */}
</Backdrop>;
```

Answer (score 0):

without a code example I am not 100 but I hope this helps... both Drawer (via passing modal in its props) and Dialog use the Backdrop component. So perhaps it is the parent div which zIndex needs to be altered? In sandbox below I found wrapping the Backdrop into a Grid and then setting the zindex on the parent/Grid works. Here's various setups of Backgrounds with Drawers and Dialogs :
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-firefly-44s63k?file=/src/temporary-drawer.js

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog/
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/

Comment: Thanks for the example! It definitely looks like it works in the codesandbox example. I'm still having some issues getting it to work in my project after wrapping the loading component and dialog components in <div> wrappers with a set zIndex. It must be something else aside from just the css of these two components that's interfering. Thanks for the example though!

Comment: yep, I've seen zIndex issues where the backdrop is above say a dialog box... If you haven't already tried.. use inspector and try selecting the div you are looking for. With Dialog and Drawers they both have backdrops so you many need to disable those. Once selected it can be easier to see where your component is located in relation to everything else. Good luck!